# Android: show Alert Dialog at any activity

Tags: android, android-activity, http-post, android-alertdialog

In my application, I first start an activity which starts a thread that reads updates from a website. If an update is available, I pop out an alert dialog. When the user presses "OK" to the dialog, a message is sent back to the server saying that the user received the update

However, The user is able to go through multiple activities, so my question is, how can I still display that dialog at any activity the user is in whenever an update occurs? I keep the update thread running until the user completely exits the app, which means I am not destroying the very first activity that starts the update thread.

Answer (score 1):

Create a BaseActivity from which all other Activities extend. That way, all your activities can use that code.

e.g.

```
public class BaseActivity
{
    public void showDialog(String msg)
    {
        // show the dialog
    }
}

public class Activity1 extends BaseActivity
{
    public void someFunction()
    {
        showDialog("activity 1");
    }
}

public class Activity2 extends BaseActivity
{
    public void someFunction()
    {
        showDialog("activity 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it's kind of different. I mean, I have to be able to call the dialog whenever appropriate if there is an update once I start my updating thread. In other words, I do not want to be calling the dialog from each class (like you're doing with someFunction()). It should be the base class that does the calling for all other classes (assuming the base class starts the update thread)

Comment: you can call showDialog() from anywhere in your BaseActivity as well... Any activity running (that extends the BaseActivity) will show the dialog. Maybe i misunderstand your question, but I think the answer still holds. If not, add code examples to your question, showing i'm wrong